# I want to have only 3 columns (departure_City_Id, arrival_City_Id, Emp_number). However, when I come to insert value , it says that I have 4 columns

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

For the Epms table, I want to have only 3 columns (departure_City_Id, arrival_City_Id, Emp_number). However, when I come to insert value, it says that I have 4 columns. The extra one for City_Id. All I want is to avoid having City_Id column in this table. I declare it because I need it just as FK.

```
CREATE TABLE City (
City_Id char(3),
state varchar(30),
Primary key (City_Id)
);


create table Emps (

Emp_number varchar(30) primary key,

City_Id char(3),

departure_City_Id char(3),
arrival_City_Id char(3),

 FOREIGN KEY (City_Id)
    REFERENCES City(City_Id),

 FOREIGN KEY (City_Id)
    REFERENCES City(City_Id)
);
```

Comment: I removed the [tag:mysql] tag because the error message you got is an Oracle error. You apparently aren't using MySQL. Though the issue is generic, and would have the same solution in MySQL, FWIW.

Comment: Yes, I am using Oracle. Still have the same problem. I cannot insert only 2 values For  departure_City_Id char(3), arrival_City_Id char(3). I am required to insert value also to CITY_ID, and I don't want have City_Id column in this table.

Comment: You are not clear. What do you mean, you cannot? What are you doing & what happens? What do you mean, you are required? Which "values"? If you don't want a column then don't declare it. Please edit clarifications into your question, not comments. Please read *any* intro to FKs, this is a basic syntax question.

Comment: The column `emps.city_id` makes not sense whatsoever - why did you include it in the table at all? And your foreign keys should be on `departure_city_id` and `arrival_city_id`

Comment: It would not run if I do not declare the foreign Key in the second table.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward, just specify e.g. `, FOREIGN KEY (arrival_city_id) REFERENCES city(city_id)` and you'll get an index.

```
CREATE TABLE emps (
  emp_number          varchar(30)  NOT NULL,
  city_id             char(3)      NOT NULL,
  departure_city_id   char(3)      NOT NULL,
  arrival_city_id     char(3)      NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (emp_number),
  KEY city_id (city_id),
  KEY departure_city_id (departure_city_id),
  KEY arrival_city_id (arrival_city_id),
  CONSTRAINT emps_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (city_id) REFERENCES city (city_id),
  CONSTRAINT emps_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (departure_city_id) REFERENCES city (city_id),
  CONSTRAINT emps_ibfk_3 FOREIGN KEY (arrival_city_id) REFERENCES city (city_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Thank you. I got this message. KEY city_id (city_id),
              *
ERROR at line 7: 
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: @Essa Read what it says. That is not a question you need to ask anyone about.

Comment: You tagged the question mysql, so I supplied a valid MySQL answer.

Comment: The error messages are Oracle error messages. Unfortunately new users of the site often tag their questions wrongly, either by mistake or because they think it will attract more eyeballs to their problem.

Answer (score 0):

> " I want is to avoid having City_Id column in this table. I declare it because I need it just as FK."

But you don't need it. The foreign key columns are the arrival and departure columns, and those are the ones you must reference in the constraint declarations:

```
create table Emps (

    Emp_number varchar(30) primary key,
    departure_City_Id char(3),
    arrival_City_Id char(3),

     FOREIGN KEY (departure_City_Id)
        REFERENCES City(City_Id),

     FOREIGN KEY (City_Id)
        REFERENCES City(arrival_City_Id)

);
```

Naming constraints is optional but you may find it helpful when debugging foreign key failures, especially when a table has multiple constraints referencing the same parent key.